# Why does isSiteLocalAddress() behave differently on the same model device running the same Android version?

Tags: java, android, android-networking

I have two Samsung Galaxy SIIs on the same network running the same version of Android (4.0.4). When this method is called ...

```
private String getIpAddress() {
    String ip = "Something's wrong, of course!";
    try {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = 
                NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while ( networkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface ni = networkInterfaces.nextElement();
            Enumeration<InetAddress>inetAddresses =
                    ni.getInetAddresses();
            while (inetAddresses.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress address = inetAddresses.nextElement();

                if (address.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                    ip = address.getHostAddress();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
        ip = "some error occured; duck-dynasty!";
    }
    return ip;
}
```

on one device it returns a valid ip address. But when I call it on the same model device as described above it returns the instantiated value; why?

I don't mean to ask why does this method fail me on a *logical* standpoint; that is obvious. I mean, why would two devices, as described, return conflicting results? Shouldn't *one* of the network interfaces' address satisfy the condition?

**Edit**

Well, it started returning a valid ip after days of not acting right. I'd provide an answer but no clue of why it was happening. Still interested in the *why* if anyone knows.

Comment: How about the number of network interfaces and number of inet addresses on both devices? You could log them all. Log all host addresses. You are using nextElement() before you examined the first one.

Comment: @greenapps: Both devices return 4 network interfaces and 2 inet addresses (one 4 and one 6). I'm not sure how knowing this helps understand why the one device doesn't return or have a site local address. I've used this code on other devices as well, never with a problem. Any other ideas.

Comment: Please comment about my doubt concerning nextElement and missing the first one. Moreover i do not understand (one 4 and one 6).

Comment: @greenapps: I understand now, I'll check it. This snippet came from a program I didn't write, but it has always functioned correctly, possibly by luck. 4 and 6 means one IPv4 and one IPv6. See my edit as well, it started working just after my previous comment.

Comment: @greenapps: The way this snippet is done is correct and does not skip the first element. [The Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) for `Enumeration` shows an example where the first element is retrieved with `.nextElement()`. The iterator knows how many elements to expect. It begins with the first element if any are available.